# Transfer of Backup from Ubuntu16.04LTS to 18.04LTS

Tags: backup

I have purchased a new PC and loaded Ubuntu 18.04LTS. My old PC with Ubuntu 16.04 is backed up to a portable expansion drive. When connecting the expansion drive to the new PC to transfer files with "restore", it fails with:

> nvalidBackendURL: missing // - relative paths not supported for scheme invalid: invalid://

Is it possible to transfer files from the old to new PC with "Backup" if so how?

Comment: 1. Please tell us **what backup program you used** in the old system; 2. Can you still run the old computer with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (and the backup program? 3. Would it be an option to connect the computers via a local network? 4. Would it be an option to connect the internal drive of the old computer to the new computer?

Comment: Old system backup program was what came with Ubuntu 16.04LTS. Note: after shutting down removing backup drive, then rebooting was asked to reconnect drive. Then when trying to restore I get measage "no

Comment: Old system backup program was what came with Ubuntu 16.04LTS. Note: after shutting down removing backup drive, then rebooting was asked to reconnect drive. Then when trying to restore I get message "no backup to restore "

Comment: I am not using that backup system, so I don't know the details. But other people are using it and know how to use it, so now that we know, I think you will get useful advice :-)

Comment: Old computer with Ubuntu 16.04 is still operating. Can access old computer with wifi and access shared files but will not allow me to transfer, responds with "you do not have permissions" even though I have set permission on the old PC.

Answer (score 0):

Good that you can access the old computer. The permissions issue can be solved.

If 'access' means 'read', the problem is permissions to write (in the new computer).

### What files to write, and where

You should be able to copy the whole `/home` directory but be very careful, when copying system directories and files and do not copy any installed programs. It is better to install the program packages that belong to the new version of Ubuntu.

I would recommend `rsync` to copy the **`/home`** directory. See `man rsync`. The trailing slash is important.

First a 'dry run' to check that things seem to get copied correctly,

```
sudo rsync -Havn mountpoint-of-old-computer/home/ /mountpoint-of-new-computer/home
```

Then do it (remove the option `n`),

```
sudo rsync -Hav mountpoint-of-old-computer/home/ /mountpoint-of-new-computer/home
```

You can use `rsync` in a similar way for single files or limited directories, but do not copy system settings unless you know what you are doing, because things may not be compatible with the new version. For example, if you have special details in the old `/etc/fstab`, it is better to look at it and modify the corresponding file in the new computer manually.

If you have a separate **`data`** partition for your personal files, ownership and permissions are less important, does not disturb the Ubuntu system, and you can copy the files as you like (as long as you have write permissions).